# Flutter agora change icon color and pin remote user on larger display

Tags: flutter, agora.io

i am using agora sdk and would like to change the color of the icons in the smaller screen. also, is there a way for me to pin the remote user on a bigger screen whenever a call initiates? additionally, is there a way for audio to come out of the ear speaker instead of loud speaker?

[image]